# How to create waaark.com like scroll?

Tags: javascript, gsap, scrollmagic

can anybody help me create [waaark.com](https://waaark.com/vision/) like scroll. On mouse scroll the document should not scroll but the animation created using tweenmax should trigger. Unlike waaark.com, I have some content below the fullscreen fold which will appear after the 8th scroll.The technologies that i'm planning to use are ScrollMagic and Tweenmax(GSAP).

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post your code and explain where the problem is.

Comment: @JamieWeston Here is a sample codepen: https://codepen.io/arun-venugopal/pen/mGwNwR

According to the above pen, it has to reveal the content below first fold after three scrolls. But in my example, it requires multiple scrolls(more than 3) to see below the fold content. Thanks in advance.